# Changing placeholder color in animation

Tags: css

I can't figure out how to make animated color change in text input.

This is the css:

```
@keyframes anim {
    0% {
        opacity: 0.2;
        color:blue;
    }

    70% {
        opacity: 1;
        color: red;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0.1;
        color: blue;
    }
}

input,
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    animation: anim 4s;

}
```

Html:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Hello" />
```

JsBin:
https://jsbin.com/yejiwipego/1/edit?html,css,output

Opacity changes fine.
I've got to be missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of got it working, but it seems the opacity of the placeholder text gets kind of messed up. I hope that this is (kind of) what you meant:

Edit; I got it working a lot better. Check the new JSFiddle

Updated version: https://jsfiddle.net/oycnfxw4/

```
element {
  --main-text-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.8);
}

input, input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: var(--main-text-color);
    -webkit-animation: anim 4s linear 1 forwards;
    animation: anim 4s linear 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes anim {
    0% {
        opacity: 0.2;
        --main-text-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.2);
    }

    70% {
        opacity: 1;
        --main-text-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0.1;
        --main-text-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
    }
}
```